# Use file content as hardcoded string

Tags: c++, g++, precompiler

**I'm looking for an easy way to use the content of a file as hardcoded string constant.**

Of course i could just copy/paste the file content into an `define` but that would require me to put `\`s at the end of each line and in front of each `"`.

I tried to use `constexpr` to make the precompiler load the file but either i did something wrong(i'm not familiar with `constexpr`) or it is not possible that way.

Here is what i tried:

```
constexpr const char* loadFile()
{
    std::string retVar;

    std::ifstream file("filename.txt");
    retVar = std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    return retVar.c_str();

}

#define FILE_CONTENT = loadFile();
```

I get the error:

```
error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr const char* loadFile()' not a return-statement
```

Maybe someone can modify my code to work as expected or maybe someone has an entirely new way to achieve my goal.

I know i could simply write a script which reads the content of a file and converts it into a `#define` but i would like to do it without additional pre-build steps.

**Edit:**
[How to embed a file into an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288279/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable) focuses on embedding binary files. I just want to use a text file's content as hard coded string.
The methods suggested there are way too heavy for what i want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed a file into an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288279/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable)

Comment: File-handling just can't be done at compile-time in C++.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk - That's way too heavy. I don't want to embed binary files. Just use the content of a text file at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to indeed copy-paste the content into your header/implementation file, but as a **raw** string literal, i.e.

```
constexpr const char *fileContent = R"~(FILE_CONTENT_GOES_HERE)~";
//               begin raw literal: ^^^^                      ^^^ end raw literal
```

where you should replace `FILE_CONTENT_GOES_HERE` with the **unmodified** content of the file. Note that the delimiter (here: `~`) can be chosen differently, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for the details.

Raw string literals are a C++11 feature that frees you from the necessity to escape anything (quotation marks, newlines etc.). Note that with C++17, you might want to optionally bind the string literal to a `std::string_view` instance and/or declare the variable as `inline`.

Comment: Works for me. Didn't know about raw string literals. Thanks.