# Embedding resources into executable using GCC on Arm?

Tags: c, linker, arm

I've used the following linker command to convert a TensorFlow model file `myv2.tflite` to "dummy" object file `myv2.o`, so that I can link it into an executable, to avoid having to drag this file separately:

`ld --relocatable --format=binary --output=myv2.o myv2.tflite`

I've done this on Ubuntu x86_64. However, I will need to do the same for Arm. I suppose I cannot reuse the same `myv2.o`? Do I have to regenerate the file on Arm using `ld` from an appropriate Arm toolchain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288279/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library so many ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose I cannot reuse the same myv2.o?

You can't that; file is an ELF 64bit x86_64 ABI object file, you need it for your target architecture

> Do I have to regenerate the file on Arm

no, there's no reason `ld` needs to run on an ARM machine,

> using ld from an appropriate Arm toolchain?

exactly, just replace `ld` with your correctly targeting linker, e.g. `arm-none-eabi-ld` if this is for baremetal. Again, this is normal cross-development: no need to run *on* the target architecture, just build *for* the target architecture.

Comment: OK, just making sure, thanks.