# How do I "compile an image" directly into the executable file in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm relatively new to C++ (but not programming as a whole), and I'm messing around with OpenGL in a C++ program being compiled with Visual Studio. I want to make it so I can:

- Have the programmer enter a file path to an image file relative to program files (i.e. `images/texture.png`)
- At compile-time, have the data of that image compiled with program files, such that the .exe (or Mac/Linux equivalent) can access that image data without actually needing the file/filepath in the same directory as the executable (as though the image was compiled directly into the .exe, not unlike static-linking a library).

The goal is to make it so 100% of my program is in a single .exe, without the need to have to carry around various data files (i.e. images) that the programmer may want the user to be unable to access or tinker with.

As it stands currently, my program is already statically-linking all libraries in use, so the compiler output is just an .exe (and a .pdb), but the program still relies on needing access to image files (which I have to copy in) in the same directory. Again, I want a single .exe I can run anywhere on my system (and potentially on other systems) by itself and have the program function.

I've heard of resource files, and they may be the solution to this problem, but I've found barely any usable information about them; everything I found was about C# or dotnet, neither of which apply to my program. I could simply be misinterpreting my research because of my unfamiliarity with C++.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Can someone care to enlighten me?

**EDIT:** Wanted to clarify that my intention is to have the image data be outputted in a "byte-per-color-value-per-pixel array" format (i.e. having a byte for R, G, B, and A per pixel, then each pixel stores sequentially) AKA the texture format OpenGL uses. Also, the linked question in one of the comments is similar, but none of the answers seemed applicable to my issue.

Comment: Windows have the concept of *resource files* (with a `.rc` ending) that are files that can be used to embed certain data into the executable program file. You might want to do some research about that.

Comment: [About Resource Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files)

Comment: A resource is clearly the right approach here. You have two obvious possibilities with it. You can convert the data to BMP format, and embed that as a bitmap resource. The good point here is that Windows has lots of functions to deal directly with bitmap resources. Alternatively, you can keep it in its original format (png, jpeg, whatever), and embed it as  binary resource. In that case, you retrieve the original data as-is, and it's up to you to display it correctly.

Comment: If you are targeting cross-platform and you don't have the magic `#embed` available, [The Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html) may be worth checking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed a file into an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288279/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable)

Comment: I'll look into resource files, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio C++  project -> Add new item: Resource File(.rc).

Right Click resource.rc file -> View Code.

Add `IDB_MY_IMAGE PNG "your path\\texture.png"` in resource.rc

Add `#define  IDB_MY_IMAGE 10001` in resource.h(created automatically) first line. 10001 is custom ID.

Test code:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>

#include"resource.h"
int main() {
    //load the resource
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_MY_IMAGE), L"PNG");
    DWORD imageSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
    LPVOID imageBuffer = LockResource(hGlobal);

   unsigned char* imageData = new unsigned char[imageSize];
    memcpy(imageData, imageBuffer, imageSize);

    /* Display the png here*/
    ////////////////
  

    ////////////////
    UnlockResource(hGlobal);
    FreeResource(hGlobal);
    delete[] imageData;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this into a blank project to test it, and while it doesn't error out all `imageData` is set to is a very short string. I put in a 512x512 .png and outputted the result to a file, and I only got 10 bytes of output. Ideally, I want the data in the format of an array of bytes, with each byte representing the r/g/b/a components of a pixel. Is `imageData` like a file address, or is it supposed to be color data and I did something wrong?

Comment: Actually, looking into it further it looks like I was just reading it wrong. It seems like imageData is closely related to the raw png data? Except there are some minor differences that make the file unreadable as a png. Again, this is not what I want, as stated in my previous comment (I'll edit the original post to clarify that that is my intention).

Comment: ImageData stores the data of png. You need to display the data (stored in char pointer) by yourself. I am not familiar with OpenGL. Take OpenCV for example. `cv::Mat img = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1, imageSize, CV_8UC1, imageData), cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    int height = img.rows;
    int width = img.cols;` And there are many ways to get the value.[OpenCV get pixel channel value from Mat image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108/opencv-get-pixel-channel-value-from-mat-image)

Comment: I figured out why the pngs weren't loading when I wrote them to a file: I was using `ofstream` to check if the output was right, but `ofstream` by default converts every `0A` in the data stream into a `0D 0A` (LF -> CRLF)! After adding a `std::ios::binary` to my ofstream the png now loads properly. I also just figured out how to load data from memory using `stb_image` so I should be good!