# How to put a file in the program and extract it after its launch

Tags: c++, file

I want to pack, for example, a photo into the program and when you run it, unpack it to the folder in which it is located. I am asking for help if I can make such a program because my c ++ is not at such a high level.

Comment: Please Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how you should ask a question correctly

Comment: Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11814544/580083.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4158900/580083, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6005520/580083, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4864866/580083.

Comment: As for finding the path of the executable: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1528298/580083, https://stackoverflow.com/q/933850/580083, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647429/580083.